# Devel output on hooks called during cron run

Tags: cron, debugging

I'm implementing a hook that is called if certain conditions are met during a cron run.

(Specifically `hook_bounce_mails_blocked($mails)` from the [Bounce](https://drupal.org/project/bounce) module)

The hook is triggered, but any output from `dpm()` functions is never shown. I do see output from `var_dump()` after cron finishes.

Is this normal behaviour? Is there a way to get devel output shown once cron finishes?

Comment: "Is there a way to get devel output shown once cron finishes?" I would like to know that as well.

Comment: @DavidCsonka Messages go in the session, so unless you can hijack the session the cron job happened in, the answer's got to be "no". Using other logging is the right way to go (as in loolooyyyy's answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the function dd() to log something during cron.

Here is the doc: https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dd/7

It will log the output to a file, which later you can investigate. I think you must have private file path set.

you could use something like this, **But be careful about XSS!**

```
$export = var_export($var, TRUE) // TRUE will cause var_export to return the output not print it.
$export = nl2br($export); // Convert new lines to <br> tag for display in HTML
$export = strreplace(' ', '&nbsp;'); // Again convert whitespace to HTML specific chatacter
watchdog('my_debug', $export); // That's it!
```

or even easier:
**but again be careful about CSSF and XSS**

```
watchdog('my_debug', '<pre>' . var_export($variable) . '</pre>');
```

**dd** is the safe drupal way to go.

### Update

From comments so you wont miss:

> ... better than dd() is ddl(), from the drupal_debug_log module that enhances > the devel module... –  DrCord

## Important point to developers.

If you search drupal.org modules there are many more to  make development easier. After you found and used them, it would sound impossible to go without them ([devel_themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) to name one). [An example search](https://www.drupal.org/search/site/devel?f%5B0%5D=&f%5B1%5D=&f%5B2%5D=im_vid_3%3A59&f%5B3%5D=&f%5B4%5D=sm_field_project_type%3Afull&f%5B5%5D=ss_meta_type%3Amodule&solrsort=iss_project_release_usage+desc).

Comment: Even better than dd() is ddl(), from the drupal_debug_log module that enhances the devel module. ddl takes what would have been output into the file and outputs it to a log area. Basically necessary for debugging cron and ajax. Also is really useful for still getting debugging output from a script that is failing partways through.